# How to configure Virtuoso URL rewrite rule to give SPARQL results in JSON?

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

JSON is available as result option in the SPARQL endpoint interface, but when configuring a rewrite rule it is missing. Currently SPARQL results options in Virtuoso 07.20.3217 are only "Automatic", "RDF/XML" and "Turtle".

[image]

How to configure the rule to give the results in JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered in reply to your email to OpenLink Support --

This was an oversight in the Conductor interface, as the SPARQL query results can be returned in any of the serialization formats available from the `/sparql` Query Form page, which includes JSON. We have logged an internal enhancement request to have these additional formats added to the Conductor URL Rewrite Rule UI.

In the meantime, you can export an existing rule through the link in the Conductor UI, to see the SQL that is used to create the selected rule. For the default RDF/XML output format, it is presented as `format=application%2Frdf%2Bxml`.

Working from [the list of supported output formats](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlprotocolendpoint/), you should be able to change the `format=application%2Frdf%2Bxml` in the exported rule to something like `format=application%2Frdf%2Bjson` to get your desired JSON output. You can then manually load the edited rule via `isql`, which will look something like:

```
DB.DBA.VHOST_REMOVE (
    lhost=>'*ini*',
    vhost=>'*ini*',
    lpath=>'/rewrite-json'
);

DB.DBA.VHOST_DEFINE (
    lhost=>'*ini*',
    vhost=>'*ini*',
    lpath=>'/rewrite-json',
    ppath=>'/',
    is_dav=>0,
    is_brws=>0,
    def_page=>'',
    vsp_user=>'dba',
    ses_vars=>0,
    opts=>vector ('browse_sheet', '', 'url_rewrite', 'http_rule_list_1'),
    is_default_host=>0
);

DB.DBA.URLREWRITE_CREATE_RULELIST ( 
    'http_rule_list_1', 1,
    vector ('http_rule_1')
);

DB.DBA.URLREWRITE_CREATE_REGEX_RULE ( 
    'http_rule_1', 1,
    '/rewrite-json',
    vector (),
    0,
    '/sparql?query=select%%20%%2A%%20where%%20%%7B%%3Fs%%20%%3Fp%%20%%3Fo%%7D%%20limit%%205&format=application%2Frdf%2Bjson',
    vector (),
    NULL,
    NULL,
    2,
    301,
    ''
);
```

***Note:*** you will not be able to edit this rewrite rule in the Conductor until this issue is fixed therein, as the JSON output format will be over-written with one of those in the current list.

Also see this article about [working with Virtuoso URL Rewrite Rules](https://medium.com/virtuoso-blog/http-url-uri-rewrite-rules-in-openlink-virtuoso-7be8e20384bd).

Comment: Thank you. I have this but I get "The statement execution did not return a result set." and I still get the results in XML.

Comment: Then I tried with `format=application%%2Fsparql-results%%2Bjson&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000` and this works.

Comment: is there are way to make the choice of formatting part of the request? I have one app that wants JSON, and another CSV and if course I'd prefer they they run the same query.

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov This site is not well suited to back-and-forth conversation. Best to raise this and future followups on the mailing list or in a support case. That said -- it seems that you won't be well served by using rewrite rules for this, unless you make that rule rather complex (or make multiple rules) and use your own URL parameter -- like `fmt=json|csv` -- to drive the rewrite, replacing `fmt=json` starting with `format=application%%2Fsparql-results%%2Bjson` as above, and `fmt=csv` similarly with `format=text%%2Fcsv`.